# Rails 7 required: true attribute not working with slim-select

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, slimselect

I am using Ruby 3 and Rails 7 in my application, and using Slim select through import map.
config/importmap.rb

```
pin "slim-select", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:slim-select@2.6.0/dist/slimselect.es.js"
```

app/views/models/demo.rb

```
class Demo < ApplicationRecord
   enum tag: %i[mvp winner bpp] 
end
```

app/views/demos/new/html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: Demo.new) do |form| %>
   <div data-controller="slim-select">
     <%= form.select :tag, Demo.tags.keys.map { |tag| [tag.humanize,tag] } , { include_blank: "--Select--"}, { class: "", data: { slim_select_target: "slimSelect" }, required: true } %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

app/javascript/controller/slim_select_controller.js

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import SlimSelect from 'slim-select'

// Connects to data-controller="slim-select"
export default class extends Controller {

  static targets = ["slimSelect"]

  connect() {
    new SlimSelect({
      select: this.slimSelectTarget
    })
  }
  
}
```

it's not displaying an error in the browser and not hitting any request to the server.
my concern is to display a browser validation error in select box where i am using slim-select.
when we use required true in any text field or select box it basically shows one pop with a mandatory field that I am not getting in a select box with slim-select. and request is not going to server also .

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's a problem with the Slimselect library because it's hiding the actual select input https://github.com/brianvoe/slim-select/issues/273.

A workaround might be, remove the required:true off the input, so it submits to the controller, and then have your controller/model validate and return and render validation errors

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already solved it, but when following the tutorials, I had the same problem, the documentation gives you everything to import and use it well. I will give you the points on how to do it in ruby on rails 7 and with inportmap, it is always best not to use the cdn unless it is just to test. But I'm going to tell you how I use it.

1. download the css and js files. the css file don't forget to rename it to scss.
2. import the js in this way:
   a) #Custom script
   pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom_scripts", under: "custom_scripts"

that is the folder I use for my js scripts
b) in the application.js folder:

```
import "./custom_scripts/slimselect.min.js";
```

3. import the scss:
   @import "slimselect"; (in application.scss)
4. your stimulus file:
   import SlimSelect from 'slim-select' (this line is not necessary) you are importing the js from the js you downloaded. This is how it should look and the stimulus file:
   import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

   // import 'slim-select/dist/slimselect.css'

   // Connects to data-controller="slim"
   export default class extends Controller {
   connect() {
   new SlimSelect({
   select: this.element,

   ```
     })
   }
   ```

   }
5. In your HTML in your select just add the data attribute like this: data: { controller: 'slim' } not like this: data: { slim_select_target: "slimSelect" }
   With this it should work perfectly, this is the way I do it, if someone has a better way welcome`enter code here`

Comment: I have used the select2 library instead of the slim-select. because i didn't get any solution at that time.